# How can I remove all characters in string after the third slash BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

How to remove all characters in string after 3.rd slash in bash by sed or awk? 
I have no idea how to.
eg. we have `http://qwe.qwe.rty/asdfgh/zxc.html`
and we need: `http://qwe.qwe.rty/`

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you still need the dots

```
echo http://qwe.qwe.rty/asdfgh/zxc.html | cut -d/ -f1-3

http://qwe.qwe.rty
```

if not pipe to `tr -d '.'`

Comment: So much simpler than sed. My first thought is always sed.

Answer (score 1):

Added one slash at the end otherwise it would be too tricky for me.
Updated according to advice.

```
awk -F"/" -v OFS=/ '{print $1,$2,$3,""}' file 
http://qwe.qwe.rty/
```

Answer (score 1):

Using parameter expansion:

```
var="http://qwe.qwe.rty/asdfgh/zxc.html"
echo ${var%*${var#*/*/*/}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more complicated but a bash-only way could be:

```
regex='^([^/]+)//([^/]+)/(.*)$' ; [[ "http://qwe.qwe.rty/asdfgh/zxc.html" =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}//${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```